# Mysql date format as text not working

Tags: mysql

i have Mysql database and one filed date which has the datatype as `text` and date stores like in below format:

```
Jan 7, 2015 9:14:11 PM
Jan 8, 2015 9:14:11 AM
...
```

Now when i write the query like below:

```
select * from mydata where date>='Jan 7, 2015 9:14:11 PM' and date <='Jan 8, 2015 9:14:11 AM'
```

Then it shows all records from the database.

How can i solve this?

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sql. To execute and see the result

```
SELECT * FROM mydata WHERE DATE_FORMAT(DATE, mm dd, yyy hh:mm:ss) >=' Jan 7, 2015 9:14:11 PM' AND DATE_FORMAT(DATE, mm dd, yyy hh:mm:ss) <='Jan 8, 2015 9:14:11 AM'
```

I think it's useful to you.

Thank you.

Comment: it gives error :`#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ':mm:ss) &gt;='Jan 7, 2015 9:14:11 PM'
LIMIT 0, 30' at line 2 `

Answer (score 0):

You have to use [str_to_date](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/date-and-time-functions.html#function_str-to-date) function to convert the text to a date. and then you can compare it with your date.

```
select * from mydata where str_to_date(`date`,'%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p')>=str_to_date('Jan 7, 2015 9:14:11 PM','%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p') and str_to_date(`date`,'%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p') <=str_to_date('Jan 8, 2015 9:14:11 AM','%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p')
```

or for a shorter and more readable statement you can use between

```
select * from mydata where str_to_date(`date`,'%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p') between str_to_date('Jan 7, 2015 9:14:11 PM','%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p') and  str_to_date('Jan 8, 2015 9:14:11 AM','%b %d, %Y %l:%m:%s %p')
```

Answer (score 0):

Use backticks or double quotes for **date** column name. It is mysql keyword.